# I have red sentences and warning in terminal of visual studio code.How can I solve that?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flask

I have been learning python from udemy.And I will start to make something with  flask.I am using visual studio code program.

```
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have written this and work in terminal.I can do anything which my teacher did.But I have problem that my teacher didn't have in terminal.There are red sentence in terminal and a warning.Actually it doesn't prevent working but I am worried that it will be problem.How can I solve that?

```
NOTE=warning is Do not use the development server in a production environment.
```

AND

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, f
unction, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], Com 
    mandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Comment: Add `conda` to your path.

Comment: what is conda ? Can you explain ? How can I add it?

Comment: What you typed in your command window. [Conda — Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: link in your second comment is written that conda is included in Anaconda and I downloaded Anaconda before

Comment: So add it to your path ...

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to add it to my path.

Comment: {sigh} Read the comment I left above "What are PATH..."

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [ask]. Also, please post your last comment as a new question as it is a different problem from the current question.